# Can devicePixelRatio be zero?

Tags: javascript, division

devicePixelRatio` in java script in various calculations. For instance Im using it in division as the denominator. Is this safe without checking if the value is zero? I assume it is but I would like to know for sure.

Thanks

Comment: If devicePixelRatio is zero, I would consider it as a bug in web browser. Expecting buggy browsers is not a good attitude, when coding webapps.

Comment: Just make the case for 0 and be done with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of whether it can be, you can define your own global variable that sets a default value:

```
DPR = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
```

use that in calculations.

This has the handy advantage of eliminating any `null` or `undefined` values as well, which are equally "dangerous" as dividing by 0.

Comment: @PabloKarlsson why don't you just test it on the supported device of your site/app

Comment: any device is or policy apparently.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I cannot give you a definitive answer, a `devicePixelRatio` of 0 does not make logical sense, so I would imagine properly implemented browsers would not have a value of 0 there. Regardless, `undefined` is absolutely a possibility. So kill two birds with one stone and use the check below, which will fail whether `devicePixelRatio` is 0 or undefined.

```
if(window.devicePixelRatio){
   //Code that depends on devicePixelRatio to have a value
}
```

Comment: I don't want to be arrogant, but my answer would be better because it does the same without requiring separate `if` statements all over the code.

Comment: I disagree without further context. It is a different answer, and a valid one. But it is not so much better than this one to warrant commenting on mine and telling me it's better. For example, what if you absolutely do not want to execute code unless you know for a fact that the DPR value is provided by window.devicePixelRatio?